# What's causing the performance difference between Bazel rules_docker zipper vs gzip?

Tags: bazel

When I run a `container_push` target in Bazel (e.g. `bazel run //product:push_target`), Bazel starts to compress the `image.tar` using `gzip`. For a 2.5GB tar file, this takes about an hour.

The specific subcommand looks like:

```
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6-ST-625e526ca8a8/bin/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/container/go/cmd/zipper/zipper_/zipper -src bazel-out/k8-fastbuild-ST-4a519fd6d3e4/bin/pipeline/product/image-layer.tar -dst bazel-out/k8-fastbuild-ST-4a519fd6d3e4/bin/pipeline/product/image-layer.tar.gz
```

Running `gzip` directly via `time gzip image-layer.tar` takes 100s.

What's causing this 36x difference in time spent?

Notes:

- The zipper command is defined via: `https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/container/go/cmd/zipper/zipper.go`
- I am running Bazel in a Ubuntu docker container on a Mac. The 100s for `gzip` was measured in the container.
- I've tried passing the `-fast` flag to the `zipper` command, but that didn't yield a significant difference

Comment: It looks like you've been pretty thorough already. I would say it's best to just open an issue with rules_docker as this seems like a real performance issue. However as of 5 days ago this set of bazel rules have been deprecated in favour of https://github.com/bazel-contrib/rules_oci/tree/main, which doesn't seem to have 'zipper' binary. So perhaps it's best to just to switch to the new rules and see if you still have a performance problem?

Comment: I was hoping that there was something obvious given that I'm inexperienced with Bazel. Either way, trying out the new rule set is probably the way to go.